# Ansible loop over a list of dicts with count as a key

Tags: loops, ansible, nested

Say I have a list of dicts like the following:

```
my_dummy_list:
  - { name: x, count: 2 }
  - { name: y, count: 5 }
  - { name: z, count: 1 }
...
```

I need to iterate over it so a task gets applied the `count` times for each `name`.

I tried to use `with_subelements`, but it requires the second argument to be a list, and thus I must transform counts to `range()` like

```
my_dummy_list:
  - { name: x, count: "{{ range(1, 3) | list }} }
  - { name: y, count: "{{ range(1, 6) | list }} }
...
```

which is unreadable, unobvious and mistakable, I really want to avoid it.

I also had an idea of using templating but it would overencumber the playbook, it's already pretty much complicated.

Will appreciate any help.

PS my task looks as follows (very simplified)

```
- name: my_task
  shell: echo {{item.0.name}}_{{item.1}}
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ my_dummy_list }}"
    - count
```

and I expect the following output

```
x_1
x_2
y_1
...
y_5
z_1
```